# Discord Python Embed

Tags: discord.py

when i try to add a footer to my discord embed code, everything is fine but the embed itself doesn't appear. I do not know how to fix it.

```
if message.content.startswith('.embed'):
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Title", description="Desc", color=0x00000)
        embedVar.add_field(name="Field1", value="robertmuha303", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="Field2", value="robertmuha303", inline=True)
        embedVar.add_field(name="Field3", value="robertmuha303", inline=True)
        embedVar.set_author(name = "123", icon_url = "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/16879430")
        embedVar.set_footer(text='\u200b',icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/uZIlRnK.png")
      
        await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```

Answer (score 1):

add `@bot.event` at the top of your on_message event

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == bot.user.id:
        return
    
    if message.content.startswith('.embed'):
        print("test")
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Title", description="Desc", color=0x00000)
        embedVar.add_field(name="Field1", value="robertmuha303", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="Field2", value="robertmuha303", inline=True)
        embedVar.add_field(name="Field3", value="robertmuha303", inline=True)
        embedVar.set_author(
            name="123", icon_url="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/16879430")
        embedVar.set_footer(
            text='\u200b', icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/uZIlRnK.png")

        await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```